Mule 4.7 with ActiveMQ 5.18.5: JMSException 'invalid location: failover' due to automatic ?socket.verifyHostname parameter - how to resolve?
I'm upgrading my application to Mule 4.7 to enable Java 17 compatibility. In this setup, I’m using JMS Connector version 1.9.6 to connect to ActiveMQ Classic. My ActiveMQ Classic dependencies include activemq-all and activemq-client, both at version 5.18.5.
Problem
When I try to deploy the application, I encounter the following error:
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Invalid location: failover:(ssl://amq.org:61617)?maxReconnectAttempts=-1?socket.verifyHostName=false)

It seems that ?socket.verifyHostname is automatically appended to the end of the connection string, resulting in a ? instead of &, which may be causing the issue.
Reproducible Example
Below is a minimal setup of the connection configuration I'm using, along with the steps to reproduce the error.
Connection Configuration (XML)
<jms:config name="ActivemqConnection" doc:name="JMS Config" doc:id="5perf46a-8b92-4c97-c980-37cda733f4b8" >
    <jms:active-mq-connection username="${username}" password="${password}" tlsContext="Config">
        <jms:xa-connection-pool minPoolSize="1" />
        <jms:factory-configuration brokerUrl="${broker.url}" />
    </jms:active-mq-connection>
    <jms:consumer-config >
        <jms:consumer-type >
            <jms:topic-consumer />
        </jms:consumer-type>
    </jms:consumer-config>
</jms:config>

broker.url=failover:(ssl://amq.org:61617)?maxReconnectAttempts=-1

Steps to Reproduce

Set up the above connection configuration within a Mule 4.7 project.

Use the activemq-all and activemq-client versions set to 5.18.5.

Deploy the project in Mule 4.7 with Java 17.


Expected Outcome: The connection string should function correctly, connecting to ActiveMQ without modification.
Actual Outcome: The parameter ?socket.verifyHostname is appended automatically, causing the following error:
Attempts and Versions Tried
I have tried using reconnection strategy instead of using maxReconnectAttempts in the URL but i'm getting the below error. I’m looking for guidance to solve this issue.
Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.toString()" because "cause" is null
org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.toString()" because "cause" is null
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.toString()" because "cause" is null
    at org.mule.runtime.api@1.7.0/org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException.<init>(MuleRuntimeException.java:46) ~[mule-api-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.mule.extensions.jms.internal.connection.provider.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionProvider.connect(ActiveMQConnectionProvider.java:136) ~[mule-jms-connector-1.9.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
    at org.mule.extensions.jms.internal.connection.provider.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionProvider.connect(ActiveMQConnectionProvider.java:67) ~[mule-jms-connector-1.9.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.extensions.support@4.7.0/org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.ClassLoaderConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(ClassLoaderConnectionProviderWrapper.java:60) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core@4.7.0/org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.ConnectionUtils.connect(ConnectionUtils.java:56) ~[mule-core-4.7.0.jar:?]


Out of curiosity, why do you need a dependency on activemq-all? If you're just doing normal client things then activemq-client should be all you need.

As per my understanding, in the jms connector config we have to provide required libraries for activemq client, activemq broker and activemq kahaDB for it to work I believe.

Did the application work correctly with different versions? If so provide details.

@aled It worked on java 8.In java17,i tried using ActiveMQ libraries version 5.15.4 and JMS version 1.9.6 and i got different error "org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport: Could not set property host on SSLSocket[hostname=null, port=0, Session(1729947627057|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)]
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport cannot access class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl (in module java.base)". I'm looking for versions that will work with java 17 and resolve this error.

@Daisy add to the attempts the configuration with the reconnection strategy.

Probably this version of the JMS connector doesn't recognize that a parameter is already in use in the URL. You could try to replace maxReconnectAttempts in the URL by a reconnection strategy in the connector.

I tried replacing maxReconnectAttempts in the URL using reconnection strategy inside the connector but I'm getting this error "Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.toString()" because "cause" is null
org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException"

Please [edit] the question to add the alternative configuration and the complete error logs.

Can anyone help me on resolving this issue?

@Daisy see my previous comment.

I have edited the question and attached the error log too :)
